# Ethereum sending with web3.js is not working today (the result is fail)

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

This is my web3.js function to send the ETH.
It works perfectly last month. But today It is not working well.
It took more than 1~5 min and then return the fail.

Some times it sent but It also takes very long time to complete the transaction.

This is my current code:

```
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/GfgWbe8c2O82N18RRSuJ'));

  // Who holds the token now?
  var myAddress = address;
  // This file is just JSON stolen from the contract page on etherscan.io under "Contract ABI"
  return await web3.eth.getBalance(myAddress);
}

const sendETHCoin = async (from_addr, to_addr, amount, private_key, fee) => {
  var content = fs.readFileSync(base_path + 'abiDefinitions/ethAbiContract.json');
  content = JSON.parse(content);
  ///////////////////////////////////
  
  // connect to Infura node
  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/GfgWbe8c2O82N18RRSuJ'));  

  // the address that will send the test transaction
  const addressFrom = from_addr;
  const privKey = private_key;

  // the destination address
  const addressTo = to_addr;
  
  var gasPrice = "0x02540BE400";
  var gasLimit = "0x250CA";
  
  if(fee == ''){
    fee = parseInt(gasPrice, 16) * parseInt(gasLimit, 16);  
  }else{
    gasPrice = parseInt(parseInt(fee)/parseInt(gasLimit, 16))+1;
    if(gasPrice < 1){
      gasPrice = 1;
    }
    gasPrice = "0x"+gasPrice.toString(16);
  }
  //gasPrice = "0x03540BE400";
  
  var txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom);
  
  const txData = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(10e9), // 10 Gwei
    to: addressTo,
    from: addressFrom,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(amount, 'wei'))
  }
  
  // Signs the given transaction data and sends it. Abstracts some of the details 
  // of buffering and serializing the transaction for web3.
   const privateKey = new Buffer(privKey, 'hex')
   const transaction = new Tx(txData)
   transaction.sign(privateKey)
   const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
   
   try {
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx)    
  }catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return err.message;
  }
  //////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check in etherscan why the transaction fails. if the transaction worked last month, probably the problem is in the gas price. last week the gas prices were too high (safe low was 50 gwei) and I see that you are sending with 10gwei, this is most probably the reason why your transactions fail. Try increasing the gas price and see if it works again

Comment: I have another question. Could you let me know how to get the current acceptable gas price in eth network?

Comment: Yes, you can use https://ethgasstation.info to check the current gas price